# Attribute Error when calling 'predict_generator' from loaded Keras model

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have trained a dual-input neural network for categorising images and saved the weights to an hdf5 file.

I am now trying to load this network and use 'predict_generator' to see how well it does on my testing set. However, upon calling 'predict_generator' I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "load_cnn.py", line 75, in <module>
     pred = loaded_model.predict_generator(test_gen, steps=36, verbose=1)
   File 
"/home/ppxjm4/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", 
line 91, in wrapper
     return func(*args, **kwargs)
   File 
"/home/ppxjm4/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", 
line 1772, in predict_generator
     verbose=verbose)
   File 
"/home/ppxjm4/anaconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", 
line 503, in predict_generator
     batch_size = x[0].shape[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I am confused about why it complains here, when during training and calling 'fit_generator()' seemed to work just fine.

Here is my code that generates the error:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import keras
from keras import optimizers
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Activation, concatenate
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau

from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_df = pd.read_pickle("collated_data.pkl")
train_df = train_df.sample(frac=1)

data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

from keras.models import model_from_json

json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()

loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("weights.best.hdf5")

print("loaded model from disk!")

loaded_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])

def generator_multiple(generator, dataframe, mode, batch_size, img_height, img_width):

    if mode == 'train':

        genX1 = generator.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=dataframe[:79000], x_col='reconstruction', y_col='label', class_mode='categorical',
            batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, target_size=(img_height, img_width), color_mode='grayscale')

        genX2 = generator.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=dataframe[:79000], x_col='observation', y_col='label', class_mode='categorical',
            batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, target_size=(img_height, img_width), color_mode='grayscale')

    if mode == 'validate':

        genX1 = generator.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=dataframe[79000:85000], x_col='reconstruction', y_col='label', class_mode='categorical',
            batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, target_size=(img_height, img_width), color_mode='grayscale')

        genX2 = generator.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=dataframe[79000:85000], x_col='observation', y_col='label', class_mode='categorical',
            batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, target_size=(img_height, img_width), color_mode='grayscale')

    if mode == 'test':

        genX1 = generator.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=dataframe[85000:], x_col='reconstruction', y_col=None, class_mode=None,
            batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, target_size=(img_height, img_width), color_mode='grayscale')

        genX2 = generator.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=dataframe[85000:], x_col='observation', y_col=None, class_mode=None,
            batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, target_size=(img_height, img_width), color_mode='grayscale')

    while True:
        X1i = genX1.next()
        X2i = genX2.next()
        yield [[X1i[0], X2i[0]], X2i[1]]


test_gen = generator_multiple(data_gen, dataframe=train_df, mode='test', batch_size=36,
                               img_height=100, img_width=100)

pred = loaded_model.predict_generator(test_gen, steps=36, verbose=1)

predicted_class_indices = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)
labels = (train_gen.class_indices)
labels = dict((v,k) for k,v in labels.items())
predictions = [labels[k] for k in predicted_class_indices]

filenames=test_gen.filenames
results=pd.DataFrame({"Filename":filenames,
                      "Predictions":predictions})
results.to_csv("results.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: What happens if you run the exact same code, just with `fit_generator` instead of `predict_generator`?

Comment: Just in case, `yield [[X1i[0], X2i[0]]` doesn't work either right?

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen this gives me a different error about the input dimensions not being what were expected

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat The dimensions aren't correct for me to just change that line of code since i'm not giving any labels. However, if I change that line and use the 'test' generator, things work fine, which suggests that it is not a problem with loading the model

Comment: what is `type(generator_multiple.next()[0][0])`?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat 'function' object has no attribute 'next'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to modify the output of my generator when using it to feed testing data to the model. The flow_from_dataframe method produces data of different dimensions when y_col and class_mode are set to None.

```
def generator_multiple(generator, dataframe, batch_size, img_height, img_width):

    genX1 = generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=dataframe, x_col="reconstruction", y_col=None, class_mode=None,
        batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, target_size=(img_height, img_width), color_mode='grayscale')

    genX2 = generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=dataframe, x_col="observation", y_col=None, class_mode=None,
        batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, target_size=(img_height, img_width), color_mode='grayscale')

    while True:
        X1i = genX1.next()
        X2i = genX2.next()
        yield [X1i, X2i]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then 1 input to your model, i recommend you try yielding a dict from your generator rather then a list, here is an example from keras it self(doc string of `fit_generator()`):

```py
def generate_arrays_from_file(path):
    while True:
        with open(path) as f:
            for line in f:
                # create numpy arrays of input data
                # and labels, from each line in the file
                x1, x2, y = process_line(line)
                yield ({'input_1': x1, 'input_2': x2}, {'output': y})

model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_from_file('/my_file.txt'),
                    steps_per_epoch=10000, epochs=10)
```

For more info, here is [keras's github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1510).